# Azure android sdk images syncing

Tags: android, azure-sql-database

I want to take some pictures and need to sync in back end server using azure android offline sync sdk. Now the byte array conversion is getting some issues.

In sdk the data type corresponding to the "blob" is "others".

Is there any idea about handling this.

The image is not viewing with the usual byte array conversion

Comment: hey rajeesh ....did you get your answer regarding blob sample code for android??? .... if you ..then plzzz share bro ....

Comment: No. We converted the bytearray format to base64 string